# error on azure web app creation using visual studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service

there is an error on when creating webapp on azure app service
i would like to use this for asp.net application but at this stage we do not have to specify the platform

here is the screenshot

[image]

even after this error application is created i am facing some other issue after deployment and not able to see detail logs

so is this error causing the problem in the application? how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer says it all, you need to register that provider into "Central US", you can achieve that using numbers of ways, the easiest one would be using the portal and just deploying the same resource to the same location.

Note that you also should have the rights to register resource providers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors#noregisteredproviderfound

Comment: i am using it for "south central us" while in error message it says "Central US"
i am not sure which provider should i register and how to register for location as there is no option for location when registering

Comment: thats because app insights (i believe this is what causes this error) is being deployed to centralus, just create app insights instance in central us manually using the portal, or register the provider manually with powershell @Raghavendra check the link I've provided, it shows portal and powershell way